# File core.clj is not under a source root error in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, edn

I am using IntelliJ IDEA in a Clojure project, I just started but I get the message "File core.clj is not under a source root", the project has 2 folders: `.idea` and `src`, inside `src` I got the `core.clj` file in which showing the structure of the project. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Fhi.png) is the photo containing the structure of the project.

I have no source root, I just created the `core.clj` and the `deps.edn` file and the `Deps_project.iml` file, nothing else, how can I solve this? Do I need to write another file?

Comment: Try to right-click on `src` folder and select `Mark Directory As | Sources Root`

Comment: I did your steps but the only option I have when I click on the `Mark Directory as` is the `Excluded` option, there is no `Sources root` on the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just two files for your project:

In file `deps.edn`

```clj
{:paths ["src"]
 :deps  {org.clojure/spec.alpha {:mvn/version "0.3.218"}}}
```

In file `src/spec_tutorial/core.clj`

```clj
(ns spec-tutorial.core
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]))
```

Note there is a correspondence between the Clojure namespace and the source file path, but beware that hyphens `-` in namespaces are translated to underscores `_` in path names.

Comment: I included that when I was following a spec tutorial, but it is showing the same thing, what else do I need?

Comment: If you compare my answer with your project, you will note several differences in the file paths and content. Try creating a new project with the two files I described and you will find it opens fine in any Clojure-enabled IDE.

Comment: Sorry for answering too late, I created a new project and it works now! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your directory tree should look like so:

```
./deps.edn
./src/spec_tutorial/core.clj
```

where the `./` prefix is unix-style shorthand for the project directory.

So, the `./src` part is determined by the `:paths` line in `deps.edn`.  The `spec_tutorial/core.clj` part is from the namespace `spec-tutorial/core`, and the `.clj` suffix is the "file-type".

Also, note that hyphens in the namespace become underscores in the file/directory names.

---

Another observation:  Do not include `:test-paths` in the file `core.clj` as seen in your screenshot.

Comment: I have the `deps.edn` file outside the `src` folder and instead I have the `core.clj` file in which I have all the code, Does it mean I need to create a new project? or I just need to change the position of the files?